# request.user.is_authenticated returning false even user is logged in. user authenticated is not working

Tags: python, django

This is my view code:

```
def home(request, category_slug=None):
    user = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user=request.user.username
        products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
        context = {
            'category': category_page,
            'products': products,
            'links': links,
            'username': user
        }
        return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Here is my frontend code

```
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated%}
      Welcome {{ user.username }}
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please share *code* not images of code https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Show us some code and some things you've already tried, don't just ask "any solution".

Comment: I also tried request.user.is_authenticated(): in my view and {{user}} in my template code

Comment: Please, can you provide errors you got? Expected output and idea what you want to achieve will be welcomed too.

Comment: I want to show the user name after user login but  request.user.is_authenticated always returns false even user is login

Comment: @AdnanRafique in your home.html give a space before last '%' in your jinja tag. In addition, why in your view you are getting username from databse, then sending it to context and in html you want to get this username in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you login to your application using "login()" function of django or django admin interface?
And before authenticated, check what does "request.user" returns. If it returns "AnonymousUser" then you are not logged in.